# Add product name with attribute color, size in Order Grid Magento

Tags: php, magento

I want to add Product name with attributes (color,size). But after using below code total record show only 2 records. Here is my code:
file name is :  app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid

```
 protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft('sales_flat_order', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id',array('customer_email'=>'customer_email'));
        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft('sales_order_status', 'sales_flat_order.status=sales_order_status.status',array('label'=>'label'));
        $collection->join(
                'sales/order_item',
                '`sales/order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id',
                array(
                     'product_name' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales/order_item`.name SEPARATOR ",")'),
                    )
                );
        $collection->getSelect()->group('entity_id');

        //$collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order_address', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id AND sales_flat_order_address.address_type = "shipping" ',array('telephone', 'email'));
        //var_dump((string)$collection->getSelect());
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

and in function _prepareColumns()

```
$this->addColumn('product_name', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('Sales')->__('Product Name'),
            'width'     => '100px',
            'index'     => 'product_name',
            'type'        => 'text',
        ));
```

Kindly help me how to add attributes with product name?

Comment: Hello, i you want to add the new fields to the product grid at that time you are required use "Renderer" in magento. Have you tried with that please, check with that hope fully your issue will be resolved.

Comment: Hi, No i am not using Renderer. Kindly tell me how I can use Renderer in sales order grid and also tell me the query to get Product name with attributes (color,size).

Comment: I am using below code to get product attributes color and size but when I print $attributes it shows nothing:                                                    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($row['entity_id']);
$attributes = $product->getAttributes();